# Output observable when slider track is clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, sliders

How do I go about about outputting the sliders value (selectedV) when the track is clicked. Currently i can only achieve this by dragging the sliders handle.

I click the track to move the handle the observable does not register.

```
self.selectedV = ko.observable(2);
```

Here is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ERz7u/21/

Comment: Use the `slideStop` event.

Answer (score 0):

As @Origineil suggested, changing the following piece of code from

```
$(element).on('slide', function (ev) {
    valueObservable(ev.value);
});
```

to

```
$(element).on('slideStop', function (ev) {
    valueObservable(ev.value);
});
```

does give the results you expect. (at least in chrome )

http://jsfiddle.net/gonefishern/ERz7u/30/